Get count of unique videos by channel in DataFrame
I'm using Python for playing with some YouTube history data in Google Colab.
My intention with this data is to get the amount of videos watched on every channel -counting only the unique videos - that is, a video might have been watched more than once.
I've already debugged the YouTube history data and I've obtained this JSON data you can use for testing directly on a DataFrame.
From this JSON data and with the following code I found, I was able to get the count of unique videos by each channel.
# Get the count of unique URLs - Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69711933/4092887
df_count = df_unique_channels_and_videos.groupby(['Channel_Name', 'Channel_URL'])["URL"].agg(["unique", "nunique"])

# Show only certain columns - Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11287278/4092887
# This is due the previous code shows *all the URLS* in a single column called "unique": 
df_count = df_count[['nunique']]  
display(df_count)

The current result with this code is as follows:



Channel_Name
Channel_URL
nunique




Channel_1
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0HfE9z_EqkywKrplcS7xAA
13


Channel_2
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0H_FFs9EqkywKrplcS7xYg
5


Channel_3
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMNfE9z_EqkywKrplcS7xYg
8



My desired result would be as follows:



Channel_Name
Channel_URL
No_of_unique_videos_viewed




Channel_1
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0HfE9z_EqkywKrplcS7xAA
13


Channel_2
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0H_FFs9EqkywKrplcS7xYg
5


Channel_3
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMNfE9z_EqkywKrplcS7xYg
8



and so on.
However, I'm unable to change (or set) the column names and I'm not sure if thgis code is the right approach.

This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43897124/16660603

# Rename the column
df_count = df_count.rename(columns={"nunique": "No_of_unique_videos_viewed"})

# Display the final DataFrame
df_count[['No_of_unique_videos_viewed']]

